# Issues of multiple undefined variables when looping

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, object, find

I have been having this issue with looping through my arrays where I get these random undefines shown on my website.  [Picture of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50t2y.png)

This is my array:

```
var quotes = [
{verses: "First quote", chapter: "Psalm 139:7-10", data: "Never be Lost", id: "like1"},
{verses: "Second quote", chapter: "Matthew 27:32-44", data: "The Crucifixion of Jesus", id: "like2"}]
```

Here are my loop and my find methods:

```
$('#like1').on('click', function () {
    $("div").find('.quote').each(function () {
        likedVerses[likedVerses.length]={'verses':$(this).html()}
    });
    $("div").find('.name').each(function () {
        likedVerses[likedVerses.length]={'name':$(this).html()}
    });
    $("div").find('.meaning').each(function () {
        likedVerses[likedVerses.length]={'meaning':$(this).html()}
    });
    $('.likedVersesHtml').html("");
    for (var j = 0; j < likedVerses.length; j++){
        $('.likedVersesHtml').append('<div>' + likedVerses[j].verses + '</div>' + '<div>' + likedVerses[j].name + '</div>' + '<div>' + likedVerses[j].meaning + '</div>');
    }
    console.log(likedVerses);
});
```

Also is there a way to have all of the objects in one array instead of having each object in separate arrays?  I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: where is `likedVerses` array defined? Also, can you share the html code instead of screenshot? Also, would `likedVerses[likedVerses.length]={'name':$(this).html()}` not be overwriting `likedVerses[likedVerses.length]={'verses':$(this).html()}`

Answer (score 0):

everyone, I solved the issue I just had to put all of my objects into the same array and now the issue is gone.

```
   var versesFind = $(".quote");
    var nameFind = $(".name");
    var meaningFind = $(".meaning")
    $("div").find(versesFind, nameFind, meaningFind).each(function () {
        likedVerses[likedVerses.length]={'verses':$(versesFind).html(), 'name':$(nameFind).html(), 'meaning':$(meaningFind).html()}
    });
```

Here is my HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Verse Generator</title>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body>
<form id="all">
    <label for="likedVersesPopup"><input type="button" id="likedVersesPopup">Liked</label>
<!--    <label for="searchLib"><input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="searchLib"></label>-->
    <div id="elements">
        <div class="quote"></div>
        <div class="name"></div>
        <div class="meaning"></div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="stopTheCycle" id="stopCycle"><label for="stopCycle" id="cycleImg"><img src="pause.svg" alt="Pause. " id="pauseAndPlay" width="16"></label>
        <div id="textSize">
            <input type="radio" name="fontSize" id="smallFont" checked="checked"><label for="smallFont" id="smallFontFont">A</label>
            <input type="radio" name="fontSize" id="medFont"><label for="medFont" id="medFontFont">A</label>
            <input type="radio" name="fontSize" id="largeFont"><label for="largeFont" id="largeFontFont">A</label>
        </div>
        <input type="button" name="like" id="like1"><label for="like1"><img src="not_liked.svg" alt="Wanna Like It? " width="16"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="likedVersesHtml">No Liked Verses</div>
</form>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="script02.js"></script>
</body>
```